TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'fetch' of object '[object global]'
I've encountered an error with my tests from a mysterious way.
Context :
I have a lot of testing files that work for everyone expect me.
In the only test that fail, the only issue is this line :
const spyOnFetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch');

I don't know why but I have this error :
 FAIL   Native  ...learner-native-app/src/sections/settings/pages/DeleteAccount/DeleteAccount.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'fetch' of object '[object global]'

      at Object.restore (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:786:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)

(node:34885) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Do you guys have an idea ?
I tried :

Change my node version with nvm
Delete homebrew node version
Updating npm version
Recloning the project
Updating yarn

Information :

Node version : 21.7.2

NPM version : 10.5.1

yarn version : 3.8.1

Jest version : 29.5.0



You can ask others for their node version. I would assume that your is too high

Already tried, It's not that :((

Jest 29.7.0 fixes this, seems it's something to do with how it sandboxes between tests.

Solution :
Node version is not compatible with my tests.
I used 20.12 and 21.7 are not compatible.

The following worked for me (I added it to the jest.setup.js script)
// Fix issue when mocking fetch
Object.defineProperty(global, 'fetch', {
  writable: true,
})

